# About javascript:history.back()

Tags: html, history.js

I’m using `javascript:history.back()` like this :

```html
<font size=4 color=red><center><b><a href="javascript:history.back()">Go back</a></b></center></font>
```

How can I force the previous page to go to the top ?
Thanks a lot.
Jacques

NB The previous page always shows its bottom.

Comment: Can you add some more information on what you want to do? maybe an image?

Comment: Thanks. I mean : the previous page should appear showing its own top. In simple HTML, I'm using #top, but this don't work with javascript:history.back()

Comment: You seem to be using HTML 3.2 … with errors in it at that. You should probably brush up on how to write HTML using a tutorial written this century.